# find user by email using ajax always get 404 not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following action on my controller:

```
def find_by_email(useremail)
  @kid = Kid.find_by_email(params[:kid_email]).first
  if !@kid.nil?
        respond_to do |format|
            format.json {  render json: @kid, success: true, error: false  }
        end
    end
end
```

with the following route:

```
get '/admin/kid/:kid_email'                 =>  "admin/kid#find_by_email"
```

I this is the ajax on my view:

```
$("#kid_email").blur(function() {
  var value = $( this ).val();
  var url = "/admin/kid/";      
  var data = {"email" : value}; 
  var dataType = "json";

  if (value != ""){
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: url,
      data: data,
      success: function(response){
        alert("EXISTE");
      },
      error: function(response){
        alert("NOOOOO");
      },
      dataType: dataType
    });
  }
});
```

But I always get 404 not found, but I have the test user on my database. Here is the console output:

```
Started GET "/admin/kid/?email=testuser%40gmail.com" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-04 12:51:50 +0100
Processing by ErrorsController#routing as JSON
  Parameters: {"email"=>"testuser@gmail.com", "a"=>"admin/kid"}
MONGODB (0.7ms) development['kids'].find({:_id=>BSON::ObjectId('514055c285216d2a950003af')}).limit(-1).sort([[:_id, :asc]])
MONGODB (25.5ms) development['$cmd'].find({"count"=>"kid_weekly_connections", "query"=>{"kid_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('514055c285216d2a950003af')}, "fields"=>nil}).limit(-1)
MONGODB (28.4ms) development['kid_weekly_connections'].find({"kid_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('514055c285216d2a950003af')}).limit(-1).sort([[:start_at, :desc]])
DEPRECATION WARNING: Passing the format in the template name is deprecated. Please pass render with :formats => [:html] instead. (called from realtime at /Users/jean/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:295)
  Rendered public/404.html (0.1ms)
Completed 404 Not Found in 68ms (Views: 8.5ms)
```

Any Idea???

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Bonus tip: I try to avoid lots of negatives in my `if` tests. So instead of `if !@kid.nil?`, you could do `if @kid.present?`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your route pattern is looking for the email address in the URL. Something like this:

```
/admin/kid/kid@example.com
```

So your JavaScript needs to start out like this:

```
$("#kid_email").blur(function() {
  var url = "/admin/kid/" + $(this).val();
  ...
});
```

Then you don't really need to set/pass that `data` object either.

Comment: That's a horrible url, in my opinion.  i would always put things like this (search terms, effectively) into a parameter rather than the url path itself. @Chris this is no criticism of you :)